# Convert AS2 Code to AS3 Format

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, format, actionscript-2

please help me out converting the code below into as3. I have no ideea what is "SHEMA" , "BASE", "GLANCE" etc for AS3. THanks a lot.
This code is being written inside a movie clip.

```
function CopyFromShema(sframe)
{
    SHEMA.gotoAndStop(sframe);
    GLANCE.filters = SHEMA.GLANCE.filters;
    BASE.filters = SHEMA.BASE.filters;
    CAPTION.filters = SHEMA.CAPTION.filters;
}
SHEMA._visible = false;
SHEMA.gotoAndStop(1);
BASE.scale9Grid = new flash.geom.Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 5);
GLANCE.scale9Grid = new flash.geom.Rectangle(10, 6, 100, 2);
onRollOver = function ()
{
    CopyFromShema(3);
}
;
onRollOut = function ()
{
    CopyFromShema(2);
}
;
onPress = function ()
{
    CopyFromShema(4);
}
;
onRelease = function ()
{
    CopyFromShema(3);
}
;
onDragOver = function ()
{
    onPress();
}
;
onDragOut = function ()
{
    onRollOut();
}
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as pointed in line "3" of provided code in question, `SHEMA.gotoAndStop(sframe);`
they are all `MovieClips` and not As2 Classes/Keywords.

everything is ok in AS3 just replace (do it for all event fucntions)

```
onRollOver = function ()
{
    CopyFromShema(3);
};
```

with As3 Event handlers

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    CopyFromShema(3);
});
```

about other MouseEvents :

1. **onRollOut** : MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT
2. **onPress** : MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN
3. **onRelease** : MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP
4. **onDragOver** : N/A (its MOUSE_OVER while MOUSE_DOWN)
5. **onDragOut** : N/A (its MOUSE_OUT while MOUSE_DOWN)

so what to do with non available events in as3? they are available but you have to handling them with bunch of available events, **[here](http://snipplr.com/view/5022/)** is an example of it.

---

### [update] why chaning AS2 to AS3?

most times, there is no real need for porting AS2 to AS3, but you can simply compile AS2 projects as swf, then embedding them in to the AS3 projects, and let them communicate with each other trough a `LocalConnection` as mentioned **[here](http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html)**

Comment: Hey Thanks payam, but BASE for example isn't somethign related to "root" or "this" ?

Comment: I know, but i need a as3 project without any as2 interferring.

Comment: @Castiel i dont know much about your variables and their structures which is not understandable via just a short piece of the code, however this new question is not about porting AS2 to AS3

Comment: Hey one more question, for the onPress, onRelease, onDragOver, onDragOut what will be the corresponding names in AS3?

Comment: @Castiel if you are using Adobe Flash Professional (or earlier Adobe Animate) just ask it from code editor auto complete, its fastest solution but the best is traveling to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html | **Adobe Docs** they are all listed inside

Comment: Yes i wa son the same exatc page, hoewever i can't find the matches. I assumed onPress is MouseEvent.Click, but the rest i don't know.

Comment: @Castiel its not good to looking for same names, press is not click because click is a more complex work (press + release), at first, take a look at their definitions, and then i'll update my answer with all of them

Comment: Ca you give me an example of onDragOver code, please?

Comment: @Castiel, - updated, and about the pic, MouseEvent.DRAG_OVER  (and EXIT) are not available -------- example was included in answer -> http://snipplr.com/view/5022/